# Use for loop with cast from reshape in r

Tags: r, for-loop, reshape

I'm try to make a series of tables with the `cast` function from the reshape package, but keep encountering the following error message:

```
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: i
```

The code I'm trying to run is the following:

```
for(i in c("var1",
           "var2",
           "var3")) {
  cast(df,
     var5 ~ i,
     margins = TRUE)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using `cast`, first you need to `melt` your data frame using appropriate id.
Please, check the syntax of `cast` function.

Hope this example would help:

#### Air quality example

```
library(reshape)
names(airquality) <- tolower(names(airquality))
aqm <- melt(airquality, id=c("month", "day"), na.rm=TRUE)

cast(aqm, day ~ month ~ variable)
cast(aqm, month ~ variable, mean)
cast(aqm, month ~ . | variable, mean)

cast(aqm, month ~ variable, mean, margins=c("grand_row", "grand_col"))
cast(aqm, day ~ month, mean, subset=variable=="ozone")
cast(aqm, month ~ variable, range)
cast(aqm, month ~ variable + result_variable, range)
cast(aqm, variable ~ month ~ result_variable,range)
```